# Grant s3:ListBucket and s3:GetObject action to the same wildcard(*) resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

So, I'm aiming to to grant partial permissions to an AWS account principal. I've a test S3 bucket called `test-bucket`. I intend to put objects into my test bucket where key's wildcard is `private-data/*`. It is known that consumers of this data want permissions to perform following actions on the data

1. `ListObjectsV2`
2. `GetObject`

This means I need to grant the AWS principals of the client accounts permission to actions

1. `s3:GetObject`
2. `s3:ListBucket`

Is it possible to construct a policy which allows clients to list files which conform with the `test-bucket/private-data/*` resource wildcard.

One solution I can think of is to

1. Grant `s3:ListBucket` action permission on `test-bucket`
2. Grant `s3:GetObject` action permission on `test-bucket/private-data/*`

The problem with the above solution is that `s3:ListBucket` grants permissions at the bucket level. Is there a mechanism to limit the access while ensuring the same S3 file structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to accomplish this, but each of them requires additional changes. I don't see an option to restrict access the way you expect while keeping the same folder structure without implementing additional access control layer.

1. Create prefixes per client, but this solution requires changing the folder structure

```json
{
    "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::id",
    "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["public/*"]}}
}
```

```json
{
    "Action": ["s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetObject"],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::id",
    "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["private-data/*"]}}
}
```

2. You can use object tag as the filter instead of prefix e.g creating a tag on all the objects considered as private-data, but this does not solve the problem of listing files using `ListBucket` method, we can restrict `ListBucket` method only by using prefix

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion"],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::id",
    "Condition": { "StringEquals": {"s3:ExistingObjectTag/data-type": "private-data"} }
}
```

3. Implement an additional layer of access control for s3, e.g. create a Lambda function that will check client permissions before sending request to s3.